# Why is my whole "cube" mesh being cut rather than just the shape of the mesh I selected when using the Boolean modifier?

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

[Here is a link to a video of what I'm doing and what's happening when using the Boolean modifier.](https://i.imgur.com/4KaRmwt.mp4) It should just cut out the shape of the round mesh I'm using rather than delete the entire "cube" mesh right? I should note that I did use and apply the array modifier on the mesh I'm using to cut.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello maybe try the Fast option, it works better sometimes, also under Solver Options you have an option called Hole Tolerant, or please share your file so that we can test: https://blend-exchange.com/